# R flatten out list hierarchy to matrix or data.frame

Tags: r, list, matrix

I would like to flatten out a list hierarchy (similar to JSON) to a matrix or data frame. Let's say that I create the following list:

```
a <- list(
  b1 = list(
     c1 = list(
       d1 = data.frame()
     ),
     c2 = data.frame()
  ),
  b2 = data.frame()
)
```

Where each letter is another level or step down the hierarchy. Then I want a function, e.g. `listToMatrix(mylist = a, steps = 2)`, that generates the following:

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "b1" "c1"
[2,] "b1" "c2"
[3,] "b2" "b2"
```

Observe that the function's argument `steps = 2` imply that it should only go 2 steps down the hierarchy. Also, if there aren't enough levels available in one direction, see `b2`, then it should keep the previous list name in the matrix.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Interesting.  Some sort of recursive apply might do it.

Comment: Just to be sure: the output matrix contains list names, not the data itself? Can we assume the nested lists all have names?

Comment: @flodel: exactly, the matrix contains the list names. They will all have names in my example. Where I will apply it, the bottom-levels (d1, c2, b2, ...) will actually store data in the form of a `data.frame` instead of an empty `list()`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: I think you are right, before I found a similar problem: [http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-flatten-a-tree-based-on-list-to-a-certain-depth-td1461535.html](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-flatten-a-tree-based-on-list-to-a-certain-depth-td1461535.html), however I couldn't manage to apply the same solution in my example. I got a bit lost in the recursion ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution. So it reads easily here, I have broken the code into two parts. Later, you can easily merge the two parts into a single function.

First, a function that gets a matrix of all the names, using recursion:

```
anames <- function(x) {

   require(plyr)
   if (is.data.frame(x)) return(NA)

   y <- do.call(rbind.fill.matrix,
                mapply(cbind, names(x), lapply(x, anames),
                       SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
   colnames(y) <- NULL

   return(y)
}

anames(a)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "b1" "c1" "d1" NA  
# [2,] "b1" "c2" NA   NA  
# [3,] "b2" NA   NA   NA
```

Then, a function that applies the given `steps` input, and fills the `NA`s like you requested:

```
listToMatrix <- function(myList, steps = Inf) {

   a <- anames(myList)
   steps <- min(steps, ncol(a) - 1)
   cols.idx <- seq_len(steps)
   a <- a[, cols.idx]
   for (j in tail(cols.idx, -1))
      a[, j] <- ifelse(is.na(a[, j]), a[, j - 1], a[, j])

   return(a)
}

listToMatrix(a, 2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "b1" "c1"
# [2,] "b1" "c2"
# [3,] "b2" "b2"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works exactly as I wanted it to :) Thanks a lot!